# Does Allure Testops/reports have any tooling for automatic flaky test detection?

Tags: automated-tests, allure, datadog, flakyness

Currently trying to figure out the best automatic flaky test detection tool for a large automation suite that spans multiple frameworks. I've considered datadog but it doesn't support one of the test frameworks I need it to.
I can't find any exact documentation on Allure testops as to whether is has any automatic flaky test detection similar to the datadog feature.
https://docs.datadoghq.com/continuous_integration/guides/flaky_test_management/

Just wondering if anyone has experience and would know or used a similar tool for this use case before?

I've Researched docs and watched videos on allure Testops and haven't been able to find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to define for yourself what is a flaky test.
Can a test with success rate less than 100% over last 14 days considered as flaky? Some would say yes and for those in Allure TestOps there is a widget
[image: top tetst cases widget]
It'll show you the worst test cases on tops the best on bottom
[image: this how it'll look like]